# htaccess not working with PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

I made my website work and removed `.php` by using the code below, but some of the PHP functions are not working (`isset()`, `empty()`, etc..).
What do you think is missing or do I have to change my action?

Here is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Use of `isset`, `empty` etc is unrelated with these rules.

Comment: Why is it some my function is not working properly, do you have any idea what to check ? or any related field that I should check ? @baikho

Comment: are u appending any get parameters in url and checking them?